# How to include only specific factor values in a mixed-model formula?

Tags: syntax, categorical-data, lme4, mixed-models, r-model-formula

I'm very new to Stack Overflow, and apologize in advance as this is most likely a very basic question, but, from the data below, I would like to incorporate only a few of the treatment groups into my model formula.

A brief look at my data:

[image: 1]

My model formula:
`fit <-glmer(Proportion_S~TREATMENT + (1|HOUR),  control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data = MotherPExp, family = poisson)`

There are a total of 8 levels within "TREATMENT". they are: CCC, CCP, CPC, CPP, PCC, PCP, PPC, PPP.
I want to include only specific treatments groups (eg: only: CCC, or CPC or PPC etc.), as the independant variable and not the entire "TREATMENT" column.
I tried specifying the different levels as follows:

`data.frame(x1 = c("PCP"), x2 = c("PPP*PCP"), x3 = c("CCP"), x4=("CPP"))`

While this worked, I am still not able to incorporate it into the formula:

`fit <-glmer(Proportion_S~ x1*x2 + x3 + (1|HOUR) + control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data = MotherPExp, family = poisson)`

I get the following error message:
`Error in data.frame(x1*x2 + x3) : object 'x1' not found`

The same error message is generated for x1:x4, even if I reduce the indepedant variables.

I would really appreciate any inputs!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a different answer up, until I realised you were doing this inside the "TREATMENT" variable(column). The `PPP*PCP` confused me. You can't cross levels within a variable, you can only cross variables within a formula

You can only use your data column headings inside a `glmer()` formula.

If you need to only run your model on certain levels you need to remove the ones you don't want from your data first.

```
library(dplyr)


MotherPExpNew <- filter(MotherPExp, TREATMENT == "PCP" | TREATMENT == "PPP" | TREATMENT == "CCP" | TREATMENT == "CPP") # only these levels used
```

The vertical line is an `OR` symbol. So this saying, where TREATMENT is equal to this value OR this value etc, put it in the new dataframe.

Then your model formula will work with the new dataframe/tibble using only those lines of data i.e. those levels.

`fit <-glmer(Proportion_S~TREATMENT + (1|HOUR),  control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data = MotherPExpNew, family = poisson)`

---

IF, however you need to "program" your formulae with variables/columns, then my old answer will help:

For formulas to work in `library(lme4)` using variables (not in your `data =`) you need to use `as.formula()` and `paste()` to turn the formula "text" into something it can read. Inside `paste` anything that is defined outside of your `data=` should be outside of the quotes. Using what you have supplied (though it is hard to test without a proper set of data being supplied), I would attempt something like this:

`fit <-glmer(as.formula(paste("Proportion_S~", x1, "*", x2, "+", x3, "+ (1|HOUR)", control=glmer(Controloptimizer="bobyqa"), data = MotherPExp, family = poisson)))`

*EDIT*
you don't need these in a data frame

`data.frame(x1 = c("PCP"), x2 = c("PPP*PCP"), x3 = c("CCP"), x4=("CPP"))`

This will suffice:

```
x1 = "PCP"
x2 = "PPP*PCP"
x3 = "CCP"
x4 = "CPP"
```